# Shell Script: Menu driven script taking in multiple options

Tags: shell

I need some suggestions for my menu driven shell script. I would like the end user of this script to be able to provide multiple options when prompted to enter the choice. The user can also enter 1 option or he/she can enter multiple options.

For eg. the script should be able to handle both options:

```
Please enter any option or options between [1 - 4]: 1 2 3 

Please enter any option or options between [1 - 4]: 1
```

Please let me know how can I made changes to my script to reflect this.

Below is the code of my script for your reference:

```
#!/bin/sh

while :
do
 clear
 echo " ******** Task performing script ******** "
 echo "1. task1 "
 echo
 echo "2. task2 "
 echo
 echo "3. task3"
 echo
 echo "4. Exit"
 echo
 echo -n "Please enter any option or options between [1 - 4]"
     read opt;
 case $opt in
1)
 echo "Performing task1 . . . .";
 for i in `cat test`
 do
 ...............
 ...............
 done;;
2)
 echo "Performing task2 . . . .";
 for i in `cat test`
 do
 ...............
 ...............
 done;;
3)
 echo "Performing task3 . . . .";
 for i in `cat test`
 do
 ...............
 ...............
 done;;
4)
 echo "Bye $USER";
 exit 1;;
*)
 echo "$opt is an invaild option";
 echo "Press [enter] key to continue. . .";
 read enterKey;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `case` statement in a `for` loop that iterates
over the value you get from the `read` statement.

```
while : do;
    # print menu
    read opts

    for opt in $opts; do  # To allow for multiple space-separated choices

        case $opt in
        ...
        esac
    done
done
```

Comment: I updated my code as per your suggestion but it is still not working:

 echo -n "Please enter option [1 - 6]"
     read opts
     for opt in $opts;
     do
     case $opt in
   ...............

     esac
   done
 done